# TinyMCE not rendering in proper element/section of page on Ajax call to populate

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, mvc-editor-templates

I'm using TinyMCE as my HTML editor in a MVC project.  On page load, everything seems to be fine (page can load multiple instances of TinyMCE), however, if I add another TinyMCE instance to the DOM through Ajax, the TextArea is placed right below the last TinyMCE that was added to the page on load.

TinyMCE working before and after page load:
[image]

Should be placement details:
[image: Should be placement details]

The issue is that "Blank" is supposed to be in a whole different section of the page, instead, it seems to "append" after the last TinyMCE.

TinyMCE is within `~/Shared/EditorTemplates/EditHtml.cshtml`:

```
@* TinyMCE 4.7.9 (2018-02-27) *@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Selector: @ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)<br />
Name: @ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)<br />

@Html.TextArea(string.Empty,
    (string)ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue
)

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        initTinyMCE(
            '#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)',
            '@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)'
        );
    });

</script>
```

JS Function in a different file (I've been testing with `selector` and `elements`):

```
function initTinyMCE(selector, name) {

    console.log('selector: ' + selector);
    console.log('name: ' + name);

    tinyMCE.init({

        //editor_selector: selector,
        selector: selector,
        mode: "exact",
        elements: name,
        //elements: "@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)",

        //inline: true, //must be on a Div (but onclick of div, editor doesn't show when content came from Ajax).

        branding: false,
        height: 250,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code',
            'code'
        ],

        relative_urls: false,
        remove_script_host: true,
        convert_urls: true,

        toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | code',
        content_css: "/Content/bootstrap.css",

        entity_encoding: 'raw',

        init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
            editor.on('blur', function (e) {
                tinyMCE.triggerSave();
            });
        }        

    });

}
```

Parent view (Slider Edit) that calls a `foreach` Banner:

```
@model x.Entities.Content.Sliders.Slider

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @* Omitting other fields *@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Banners", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div id="Banners_@Model.Oid" class="sortable col-md-10">
            @foreach (var banner in Model.Banners.OrderByDescending(b => b.Order.HasValue).ThenBy(b => b.Order).ThenBy(b => b.Name))
            {
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Banners/_Edit.cshtml", banner)
            }
        </div>

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Banners, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="float: right;">
                <br />
                @Ajax.ActionLink(
                    "Add Banner",
                    "Newbanner",
                    "Banners",
                    new { id = Model.Oid },
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "GET",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                        UpdateTargetId = "Banners_" + @Model.Oid,
                    },
                    new { style = "btn btn-info" }
                )
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

BannerController for `Newbanner`:

```
public PartialViewResult NewBanner(Guid id)
{
    Banner newBanner = new Banner() { SliderID = id, Name = "New Banner", Content = "Blank" };
    return PartialView("_Edit", newBanner);
}
```

Each Banner (~/Views/Banners/_Edit.cshtml):

```
@model x.Entities.Content.Sliders.Banner

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Banners"))
{

    @* OMitting other fields *@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Banner class with UIHint:

```
public class Banner : BaseObject
{
    //Omitting ther fields

    [UIHint("EditHtml")]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }

}
```

Please let me know if I should add any additional information.

Comment: _"if I add another TinyMCE instance to the DOM through Ajax"_ ... where is the code that does this? You have only shared the code that initializes TinyMCE on document ready, which is the one you say works.

Comment: The Ajax call is retrieving "~/Shared/EditorTemplates/EditHtml.cshtml", but I will post all my code in an hour or so.

Comment: @zgood I've updated the OP, let me know if I am still missing anything crutial.

Comment: maybe it has something to do with adding tinymce editors dynamically after page load. have you tried something like this: `tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, "here_place_editor_class or ID");` from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252263/add-a-tinymce-editor-dynamically-when-you-already-have-tinymce-instances-on-your) after you have initialized your other instance

Comment: It's just the tinymce field that doesn't get appended properly correct? the other fields in the _Edit partial get appended fine?

Comment: All other fields are fine, just TinyMCE's text area (iFrame) not being initialized properly.  If I Add a new Banner (fill in all fields), it is saved properly, then, when I re-enter Edit of that Slider, the two Banner instances of TinyMCE are fine.  So just Ajax call, it isn't making sense to me, the TinyMCE iFrame is in the wrong place.  `tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, "#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)");` doesn't seem to be doing any for me.

Comment: New find, running `console.log(tinymce.EditorManager.editors);` will show 2 tinyMCE instances on page load (this is the correct amount I should see), however, if I call my Ajax load, and run the log again, it only shows 1, which is the new tinyMCE editor.  The other two are NOT in the EditorManager from some reason.